# Increment in for loop give different answers

Tags: java

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i= 1; i < 2; i++) {
            System.out.println(i);
            System.out.println(++i);

            int a = 1;
            System.out.println(a++);
            System.out.println(++a);
        }
    }
}
```

The output here is 1,2 and 1,3. We are doing post-increment and pre-increment in both the cases why I am getting different results?

Comment: you need to know about post and pre incremental operator in java

Comment: Use a debugger, and see how values are changing with iterations...

Comment: `for (int i= 1; i < 2; i++)` <-- because this `i++` gets executed after each iteration. Please have a look at the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html).

Comment: Dupicate suggestion would have to be in context of loop, not only pre/post incrementation

Comment: The loop here is totally irrelevant.

Comment: @AndyTurner It isn't. The OP is asking why `a++ ... ++a` behaves different than `i++ ... ++i`, and the reason is that `i++` doesn't get executed until the end of each iteration, while `a++` gets executed immediately (so `i` and `a` will have different values).

Comment: @BackSlash Even if it were executed, the result would be 2,3 so the question doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 3):

Because post increment happens at the end of the iteration.

Hence the below code :

```
for (int i= 1; i < 2; i++) {
        System.out.println(i);
        System.out.println(++i);
```

Will work something like this:

```
int i = 1;
System.out.println(i); // i is still 1
System.out.println(++i); // pre increment making i to 2 and then print
i++;
if(i<2) 
// iterate again
```

However, in second case:

```
int a = 1;
  System.out.println(a++); // post increment first print 1 and then change a to 2
  System.out.println(++a); // pre increment a now changed to 3
```

Comment: Why down vote ?

Comment: "post increment does not work for the first iteration in for loop" is incorrect. Are you trying to say that the last term in the for loop, the i++ is evaluated at the end of the loop? The way a post increment works does not change depending on which iteration you're in.

Comment: @matt  yes, that is what I shared in by explaining where in post increment happens in the end

Comment: @matt Also updated the statement to avoid confusion

Comment: Makes sense now, cheers.

Answer (score 2):

```
    System.out.println(i); // 1 (initial value)
    System.out.println(++i); // 2 (pre increment returns the value after increment)

    int a = 1;
    System.out.println(a++); // 1 (initial value prior to increment, since post increment 
                             // returns the value prior to increment)
    System.out.println(++a); // 3 (pre increment returns the value after increment)
```

The `i++` in the loop's definition only takes place at the end of each iteration. You never print the value of `i` after `i++` is executed, since the loop terminates after the first iteration.

BTW, if `i++` was executed prior to `System.out.println(i);`, you'd still get a different output (compared to the last two `println` statements) - `2` followed by `3`.

Answer (score 1):

The [general structure of a for loop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.1) (more precisely: *this type of basic for statement*) is:

```
for ([ForInit]; [Expression]; [ForUpdate]) Statement
```

The equivalent while loop is:

```
[ForInit];
while ([Expression]) {
  Statement;
  [ForUpdate];
}
```

In other words, the update is executed after the loop body.

So your code is equivalent to:

```
// ForInit
int i = 1;
while (/* Expression */ i < 2) {
  // Statement
  System.out.println(i);
  System.out.println(++i);

  int a = 1;
  System.out.println(a++);
  System.out.println(++a);

  // ForUpdate
  i++;
}
```

Hopefully it is then easy to see why there is a difference in the output.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, the post-increment is not called. If you understand how a for loop works, you will know that the increment section is not executed the very first time. The initialization section, here int i = 1, and the condition checking - i < 2 is validated. The increment section is invoked only after each iteration.

In the second case, the post-increment is performed and hence the difference in values. You should focus more on the basics of looping.

Answer (score 0):

System.out.println(i);

i isn't postincremented here. The answers would be the same if it were:

```
System.out.println(i++);
System.out.println(++i);

int a = 1;
System.out.println(a++);
System.out.println(++a);



for (int i= 1; i < 2; **i++)**
```

doesn't do anything until a pass through loop is done.